# How to resume from the UserControl where i closed the application?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have added 8 Usercontrol. These Usercontrol will open by clicking the Previous/Next buttons. I need to resume from the UserControl which I opened before closing the application. For example I closed the application in 5th UserControl. When i am opening the application again,I need to resume from the 5th UserControl.
I added those 8 UserControls in UserControlViewModel.

```
    private UserControlViewModel _userControlViewModel;
    public MainPanelViewModel()
    {         
       _userControlViewModel= new UserControlViewModel();        
    }
```

But everytime it is creating a new instance when calling the MainPanelViewModel constructor. So that UserControl is not resuming from the UserControl which I opened in before execution. 
How to achieve this one?

Comment: What kind of application is this? Windows forms or WPF? You can store the current tab position in some data store, file or database and check it when form is opened and load that particular tab.

Comment: Maybe [Application Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/application-settings-overview)?

Comment: I am doing this in WPF.

Comment: Application Settings can be used in a WPF app.  Look it up.  You could simply store an Integer in settings and use that to determine which control to load when your program starts.